# What should our 'Tour' and 'Help' documentation contain?

Tags: discussion

It may be a little early, but no harm in putting this out there now and open this up for discussion.

Specifically, what should our 'Ask about' and 'Do not ask about' on the [Tour page](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/tour) contain?  Currently it has:

The generic:

```
Ask about...

Specific issues with history of science and math
Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
```

and

```
Don't ask about...

Anything not directly related to history of science and math
Questions that are primarily opinion-based
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer
```

and especially elaborated on in our [Help centre](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Anything not directly related to history of science and math ***as defined in the help center***.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion for the last bit:

> Don't ask about...

```
Anything not directly related to the history of science, the history of math or the history of engineering
Questions related solely to scientific and/or mathematical concepts
Questions that are primarily opinion-based
```

We can update this and the "ask about" bit when we decide which fields are and are not on-topic.

Comment: The mathematician (or just the general nit-picker) in me forces me to note that this would mean, taken strictly, each question must be directly related to: (history of science or math) **and** engineering. This is a bit strict. :-)

Comment: @quid Ahhhhhhh. Got me there.